# Counting the no. of commas across multiple fields using SQL

Tags: sql, field

I've 3 fields which contain only text. However, i want to add a calculated field which counts the number of commas in each of these 3 fields and displays it separately in the adjacent column. The snippet of SQL i use is shown below. How can i build the calculated field?

```
SELECT week, client_I, client_II, client_III
FROM quality_control_test;
```

Please advise!

Comment: Which version of RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

well, you can "count" the number of a given character in a string, by using this:

```
length(c) - length(replace(c,',',''))
```

I'm assume you can figure out how to leverage that for your own query ;)